# Can I telnet from Linux to Windows when authentication is NTLM only?

Tags: linux, windows, telnet

I've got a Windows telnet server set up to accept NTLM only (password authentication mechanism is disabled).

Is there any way to telnet to this server from Linux, using a "standard" telnet client found in Fedora core 6 (I can't find version information)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where Avery is going w/ Samba / Likewise Open.

There isn't a TELNET client for Linux that I'm aware of that has support for the Microsoft-proprietary NTLM TELNET authentication. If you want to use the standard TELNET client, stop requiring NTLM authentication. (It's really useless anyway, since TELNET runs everything else in the clear and is wholly vulnerable to TCP hijacking, just like Avery says.)

Comment: Because I was tired and not thinking clearly. +1 for pointing out that SysAdmins need coffee in the morning for a *good* reason. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First off, telnet is still incredibly insecure, so I hope you're using this over a LAN.  Even though the authentication is secure, someone can still evesdrop on your session, and given time, that means you will be sending a password in the clear, over the wire.

If you are intent on doing shell work for Windows, you may wish to look at [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/).  Using SSH will eliminate the need for NTLM authentication and allow you to work from a wider range of clients.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use the client and server I specified in the question (as insecure as it is).

Where would Samba be relevant here?

Comment: bah, too early in the morning for answers (6:30am).  Redacting it.